# How to make a function change variables while in a while loop?

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def lol(done, really_done):
    done = done + 1
    print(done)
    if done == 10:
        really_done = True

really_done = False
while really_done == False:
    done = 0
    lol(done, really_done)
```

so whenever I run this code, it does not change the value of done, it always stays at 1. I want it to change to 10 and stop the while loop. I only want it in this type of module.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer a [for loop?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Comment: As an aside, may I humbly suggest that you learn a bit more about python?  Generally speaking, when you ask questions on a professional board, the professionals there kind of expect you to be well-versed in the basics already.

Comment: The `done` in function `lol()` is not the same one that the `while` loop below it is using because it's an argument/local variable in the function. The simplest, but not the best, fix would be to add a "global done" at the beginning of the function to correct that and quit passing it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is that you want to save the state of `done` and `really_done` across calls to `lol`. There are several ways to do this, so I'll toss in another possibility.

A common way to keep state for a function is with a class:

```
class Lol:

    def __init__(self, done=0, max_done=10):
        self.done = done
        self.max_done = max_done

    @property
    def really_done(self):
        self.done >= self.really_done

    def lol(self):
        self.done += 1

lol = Lol()
while not lol.really_done:
    lol.lol()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `really_done` variable inside the `lol` function and the `really_done` variable at the module level live in different *scopes* (also commonly called *namespaces*).  The former is a *local variable* and the latter is a *global variable*.

```
def lol(done, really_done):
    done = done + 1               ---+
    print(done)                      |
    if done == 10:                   +--- the local scope (inside a `def`)
        really_done = True        ---+

really_done = False               ---+
while really_done == False:          |
    done = 0                         +--- the GLOBAL scope 
    lol(done, really_done)        ---+
```

You can not signal to the `while` loop that you want to exit in this way, because the local scope is isolated from the GLOBAL scope. Instead, the function will need to signal to the caller that you're really done by using a return value:

```
def lol(done, really_done):
    done = done + 1
    print(done)
    if done == 10:
        really_done = True
    return done, really_done

done = 0
really_done = False
while really_done == False:
    done, really_done = lol(done, really_done)
```

Using the return value allows information from the local scope (function namespace) to be passed back out to the global scope (module namespace).  This is similar to the same way that passing in arguments to a function allows information from the outer scope (module namespace) to be received as information in the local scope (function namespace).

Answer (score -2):

You are resetting the value of `done` everytime you run the loop. Not only that - you're trying to change the value a global variable, but is instead changing the value of a simple parameter, so `lol(done)` isn't actually doing anything.

If you want to keep it in a function, you should use the keyword `global` to indicate you're using the global variables:

```py
def lol():
    global done
    global really_done

    done += 1
    really_done = done == 10

really_done = False
done = 0
while not really_done:
    lol()
```

This should work, but **it's bad code - you shouldn't use `global` if it's not a real need**. Not changing much of your code, you could use `return` to keep your code cleaner:

```py
def lol(done, really_done):
    done += 1
    really_done = done == 10

    return done, really_done

really_done = False
done = 0
while not really_done:
   done, really_done = lol(done, really_done)
```

That makes it a bit better. Yet, we could solve everything by simply looping a `range` with a `for`:

```py
done = 0
for n in range(10):
    done += 1
print(done)
```